# Another solution to comparing lists, dictionaries or sets? I've tried everything

Tags: python, sql

I have data within a sql database where each row has a unique identifier and a bunch of codes that are separated by commas. What I want to do is make a list where each identifier has only one code per row. Which I've done after importing data:

```
rows = cur.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    (pid, codelist) = row
    codes = set()
  for x in codelist.split(','):
     if len(x.strip()) > 0: codes.add(x.strip())
  for code in codes:
     print (pid, code)
```

Now I want to create 2 separate lists of data from pre-Event to post-Event and finally, create a list that only includes unique identifiers and codes that aren't in time point A. I've tried comparing sets, lists, dictionaries, but I will either get identifiers and codes that are common to both or some codes that are only unique to post-Event, however its somehow omits some other codes that are unique to post-Event. I suspect my data structures are incorrect or there is something wrong with my for loops, but this is the closest to what I want but is missing data for some reason:

```
rows = cur.fetchall()
rows2 = cur.fetchall()
for row in rows:
   (pid, codelist) = row
   codes = set()
   preEvent= OrderedDict()
   for x in codelist.split(','):
       if len(x.strip()) > 0: codes.add(x.strip())
    for code in codes:
        preEvent[pid]=code
        a=list(preEvent.items())
    for row2 in rows2:
        (pid, codelist) = row2
        codes2= set()
        postEvent= OrderedDict()
        for x in codelist.split(','):
            if len(x.strip()) > 0: codes2.add(x.strip())
        for code in codes2:
            postEvent[pid]=code
            b=list(postEvent.items())
        c=[]
        for i in range(0, len(b)):
         if b[i] not in a:
            c.append(b)
            print(c)
```

I'm not sure why other attempts at set(b)-set(a) don't work, which would have been an easier solution. When I do this I get a bunch of duplicates that match instead of a new set that only has codes unique to set(b). This should probably be easy but I'm at a huge loss!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `rows` is a plain `list`, like a `list` of `tuple`s

```
[(10, 'a'), (10, 'b'), (10, 'c'), (20, 'd') ... ]
```

I would guess something like:

```
unique_in_rows = [val for val in rows if val not in rows2]
```

This iterates over all elements in `rows` and checks if it is not in `rows2`. If that condition is true, the element will be appended to `unique_in_rows`.

Comment: Thanks Nils. This still doesn't work for some reason. My list looks like this though: [(100, '401.1')]
[(100, '441.4')]
[(100, '244.9')]
[(100, '244.9')]
[(100, '250.00')]
[(100, '244.9')]
[(100, '401.1')]                                                      but in a columnar fashion. I tried to see if I just needed to flatten the list to see if then the code would work, but still doesn't.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and state the input and desired output lists?